# Loop between element with hasClass in jQuery

Tags: jquery, each

I've little cards like this:

```
<div class="card bordered" data-price="99.00">
    <div class="card-header"> Item 1 </div>
    <div class="card-content">Text</div>
</div>
```

Sometime a card can be active so I change the element class like this:

```
<div class="card bordered" data-price="99.00">
    <div class="card-header alert alert-danger"> Item 1 </div>
    <div class="card-content">Text</div>
</div>
```

Now, I need to loop into all my `.card` but only if the classes `alert alert-danger` are in my `div.card-header` and alert the `data-price`.

I already tried:

```
$('.card > .card-header').hasClass('alert alert-danger').each(function(i) {
    alert($(this).data('price'));
});
```

Comment: `$('.card > .card-header.alert.alert-danger')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)** instead of **[`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)**, **[`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)** returns a Boolean value not jQuery object. Also `data-price` attribute is defined on it's parent, so use `parent()` to get it's parent.

```js
$('.card > .card-header').filter('.alert.alert-danger').each(function(i) {
  alert($(this).parent().data('price'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card bordered" data-price="99.00">
  <div class="card-header alert alert-danger">Item 1</div>
  <div class="card-content">Text</div>
</div>
```

Or simply using single selector

```js
$('.card > .card-header.alert.alert-danger').each(function(i) {
    alert($(this).parent().data('price'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card bordered" data-price="99.00">
  <div class="card-header alert alert-danger">Item 1</div>
  <div class="card-content">Text</div>
</div>
```

If you want to get the parent then you can use **[`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)**

```js
$('.card').has('.card-header.alert.alert-danger').each(function(i) {
  alert($(this).data('price'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card bordered" data-price="99.00">
  <div class="card-header alert alert-danger">Item 1</div>
  <div class="card-content">Text</div>
</div>
```